# Error on clickTag script in HTML5 animated ads banner

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, ads

I'm using this script for a Ads Banner on a client website. This js code is generated from another agency and seems that it doesn't work because it shows an error when the user click on the banner.

This is the error message:

> "The requested URL /6255/REVIVE_ADSERVER_CLICK_URL was not found on this server."

And this is the code that have the `clickTag`:

```
  <script>
    var clickTag = "{REVIVE_ADSERVER_CLICK_URL}";
  </script>


    
<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="support">var gwd = gwd || {};
gwd.actions = gwd.actions || {};
gwd.actions.events = gwd.actions.events || {};
gwd.actions.events.getElementById = function (id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!element) {
        var pageDeck = document.querySelector("gwd-pagedeck");
        if (pageDeck) {
            if (typeof pageDeck.getElementById === "function") {
                element = pageDeck.getElementById(id)
            }
        }
    }
    if (!element) {
        switch (id) {
            case"document.body":
                element = document.body;
                break;
            case"document":
                element = document;
                break;
            case"window":
                element = window;
                break;
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    return element
};
gwd.actions.events.addHandler = function (eventTarget, eventName, eventHandler, useCapture) {
    var targetElement = gwd.actions.events.getElementById(eventTarget);
    if (targetElement) {
        targetElement.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, useCapture)
    }
};
gwd.actions.events.removeHandler = function (eventTarget, eventName, eventHandler, useCapture) {
    var targetElement = gwd.actions.events.getElementById(eventTarget);
    if (targetElement) {
        targetElement.removeEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, useCapture)
    }
};
gwd.actions.events.setInlineStyle = function (id, styles) {
    var element = gwd.actions.events.getElementById(id);
    if (!element || !styles) {
        return
    }
    var transitionProperty = element.style.transition !== undefined ? "transition" : "-webkit-transition";
    var prevTransition = element.style[transitionProperty];
    var splitStyles = styles.split(/\s*;\s*/);
    var nameValue;
    splitStyles.forEach(function (splitStyle) {
        if (splitStyle) {
            var regex = new RegExp("[:](?![/]{2})");
            nameValue = splitStyle.split(regex);
            nameValue[1] = nameValue[1] ? nameValue[1].trim() : null;
            if (!(nameValue[0] && nameValue[1])) {
                return
            }
            element.style.setProperty(nameValue[0], nameValue[1])
        }
    });

    function restoreTransition(event) {
        var el = event.target;
        el.style.transition = prevTransition;
        el.removeEventListener(event.type, restoreTransition, false)
    }

    element.addEventListener("transitionend", restoreTransition, false);
    element.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", restoreTransition, false)
};
gwd.actions.gwdGenericad = gwd.actions.gwdGenericad || {};
gwd.actions.gwdGenericad.exit = function (receiver, url, opt_collapseOnExit, opt_pageId) {
    gwd.actions.events.getElementById(receiver).exit(url, opt_collapseOnExit, opt_pageId)
}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">window.gwd = window.gwd || {};
gwd.clickTAG = function (event) {
    clickTAGvalue = dhtml.getVar("clickTAG", "REVIVE_ADSERVER_CLICK_URL");
    landingpagetarget = dhtml.getVar("landingPageTarget", "_blank");
    window.open(clickTAGvalue, landingpagetarget)
};
gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action = function (event) {
    gwd.actions.gwdGenericad.exit("gwd-ad", "REVIVE_ADSERVER_CLICK_URL", true, "page1")
}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="registration">gwd.actions.events.registerEventHandlers = function (event) {
    gwd.actions.events.addHandler("gwd-taparea_1", "action", gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action, false);
    gwd.actions.events.addHandler("gwd-taparea_1", "action", gwd.clickTAG, false);
    gwd.actions.events.addHandler("gwd-taparea_1", "action", gwd.clickTAG, false)
};
gwd.actions.events.deregisterEventHandlers = function (event) {
    gwd.actions.events.removeHandler("gwd-taparea_1", "action", gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action, false);
    gwd.actions.events.removeHandler("gwd-taparea_1", "action", gwd.clickTAG, false);
    gwd.actions.events.removeHandler("gwd-taparea_1", "action", gwd.clickTAG, false)
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", gwd.actions.events.registerEventHandlers);
document.addEventListener("unload", gwd.actions.events.deregisterEventHandlers)</script>
<script data-source="gwdtaparea_min.js" data-version="7" data-exports-type="gwd-taparea">(function () {/*

 Copyright The Closure Library Authors.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
    'use strict';
    var f, g = "function" == typeof Object.create ? Object.create : function (a) {
        var b = function () {
        };
        b.prototype = a;
        return new b
    }, h;
    if ("function" == typeof Object.setPrototypeOf) h = Object.setPrototypeOf; else {
        var k;
        a:{
            var l = {o: !0}, m = {};
            try {
                m.__proto__ = l;
                k = m.o;
                break a
            } catch (a) {
            }
            k = !1
        }
        h = k ? function (a, b) {
            a.__proto__ = b;
            if (a.__proto__ !== b) throw new TypeError(a + " is not extensible");
            return a
        } : null
    }
    var n = h, q = this || self, r = function (a, b) {
        function c() {
        }

        c.prototype = b.prototype;
        a.I = b.prototype;
        a.prototype = new c;
        a.prototype.constructor = a;
        a.J = function (d, e, I) {
            for (var x = Array(arguments.length - 2), p = 2; p < arguments.length; p++) x[p - 2] = arguments[p];
            return b.prototype[e].apply(d, x)
        }
    };
    var t = function (a, b, c) {
        c = void 0 === c ? null : c;
        var d = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
        d.initCustomEvent(a, !0, !0, c);
        b.dispatchEvent(d);
        return d
    };

    function u(a) {
        if (Error.captureStackTrace) Error.captureStackTrace(this, u); else {
            var b = Error().stack;
            b && (this.stack = b)
        }
        a && (this.message = String(a))
    }

    r(u, Error);
    u.prototype.name = "CustomError";
    var v = function (a, b) {
        a = a.split("%s");
        for (var c = "", d = a.length - 1, e = 0; e < d; e++) c += a[e] + (e < b.length ? b[e] : "%s");
        u.call(this, c + a[d])
    };
    r(v, u);
    v.prototype.name = "AssertionError";
    var w = function (a, b, c) {
        if (!a) {
            var d = "Assertion failed";
            if (b) {
                d += ": " + b;
                var e = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2)
            }
            throw new v("" + d, e || []);
        }
        return a
    }, y = function (a, b) {
        throw new v("Failure" + (a ? ": " + a : ""), Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    };
    var A = function (a, b) {
        this.f = b === z ? a : ""
    };
    A.prototype.A = !0;
    A.prototype.v = function () {
        return this.f.toString()
    };
    A.prototype.toString = function () {
        return "SafeUrl{" + this.f + "}"
    };
    var B = /^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp):|[^:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/i, z = {};
    var C = [], D = function (a) {
        a = C.indexOf(a);
        0 <= a && C.splice(a, 1)
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", function (a) {
        for (var b = 0; b < C.length; b++) if (25 > Math.abs(a.clientX - C[b].s) && 25 > Math.abs(a.clientY - C[b].u) || 25 > Math.abs(a.screenX - C[b].G) && 25 > Math.abs(a.screenY - C[b].H)) C.splice(b, 1), a.stopPropagation(), a.preventDefault()
    }, !0);
    var E = function () {
        var a = HTMLElement.call(this) || this;
        a.l = 0;
        a.m = 0;
        a.c = null;
        a.h = null;
        a.b = null;
        a.g = null;
        a.i = a.B.bind(a);
        a.a = !0;
        return a
    }, F = HTMLElement;
    E.prototype = g(F.prototype);
    E.prototype.constructor = E;
    if (n) n(E, F); else for (var G in F) if ("prototype" != G) if (Object.defineProperties) {
        var H = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(F, G);
        H && Object.defineProperty(E, G, H)
    } else E[G] = F[G];
    E.I = F.prototype;
    f = E.prototype;
    f.connectedCallback = function () {
        this.b || (this.c = this.j.bind(this), this.h = this.F.bind(this), this.b = this.D.bind(this), this.g = this.C.bind(this));
        this.addEventListener("click", this.c, !1);
        this.addEventListener("touchstart", this.h, !1);
        this.addEventListener("action", this.i, !1)
    };
    f.disconnectedCallback = function () {
        this.removeEventListener("click", this.c, !1);
        this.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.h, !1);
        this.removeEventListener("action", this.i, !1)
    };
    f.j = function (a) {
        this.a && t("action", this, a);
        this.a = !0
    };
    f.F = function (a) {
        this.addEventListener("touchmove", this.b, !1);
        this.addEventListener("touchend", this.g, !1);
        a = a.touches[0];
        this.l = a.clientX;
        this.m = a.clientY
    };
    f.C = function (a) {
        this.j(a);
        this.removeEventListener("touchmove", this.b, !1);
        this.removeEventListener("touchend", this.g, !1);
        a = a.changedTouches[0];
        a = {s: a.clientX, u: a.clientY, G: a.screenX, H: a.screenY};
        C.push(a);
        setTimeout(D.bind(null, a), 2500)
    };
    f.D = function (a) {
        a = a.touches[0];
        this.a = this.a && 10 >= Math.abs(this.l - a.clientX) && 10 >= Math.abs(this.m - a.clientY)
    };
    f.B = function (a) {
        var b = this.getAttribute("exit-id"), c = this.getAttribute("product-index"),
            d = this.getAttribute("exit-override-url");
        d && !t("tapareaexit", this, {
            "exit-id": b,
            url: d,
            "product-index": c,
            "action-event": a.detail
        }).detail.handled && (d instanceof A ? a = d : (a = d, a instanceof A || (a = "object" == typeof a && a.A ? a.v() : String(a), w(B.test(a), "%s does not match the safe URL pattern", a) || (a = "about:invalid#zClosurez"), a = new A(a, z))), b = a, a = q.open, b instanceof A && b.constructor === A ? b = b.f : (c = typeof b, y("expected object of type SafeUrl, got '" +
            b + "' of type " + ("object" != c ? c : b ? Array.isArray(b) ? "array" : c : "null")), b = "type_error:SafeUrl"), a.call(q, b, ""))
    };
    customElements.define("gwd-taparea", E);
}).call(this);
</script>
```

How to fix this error so the clicks work again on the Ads Banner?
Please don't reply with a
`var clickTag = "https://www.google.com/";`

solution because it seems that the clickTag var should be dynamic.

Comment: Please format your code better, I don't want too.

Comment: @Cooper yes, i have formatted it now